# Разница между const LPSTR и const char*

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Есть такой код:

```
const LPSTR str = "str";
const char* str2 = "str";

int main()
{
    char* w = str;
    char* w2 = str2; //error: cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'char *'
    return 0;
}
```

Почему появляется такая ошибка понятно. Но почему такой ошибки нет строчкой выше, когда используется `LPSTR`? Ведь это только `typedef char* LPSTR;`

Comment: Компилятор Visual C++?

Comment: Да, компилятор VS2015

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Потому что `typedef` - это не макрос, т.е. не текстовая подстановка. В

```
const LPSTR str = "str";
```

`const` уже относится к самому `str`, а не к указуемым данным. То есть это эквивалентно следующему объявлению

```
char *const str = "str";
```

Отличие от

```
const char* str2 = "str";
```

очевидно.

Поэтому и нет ошибки в `char* w = str;`.

---

Формально в современном С++

```
const LPSTR str = "str";
```

является некорректным кодом. Указатель на *некостантный* `char` нельзя просто так поставить указывать на строковый литерал.

Answer (score 5):

для начала разберемся с типами переменных:

- Инициализация `const` указателя на `char` посредством строкового литерала. Наличие `const` слева может вводить в заблуждение, так как он применяется ко всему типу `LPSTR`, а не только к его левой части, то бишь к `char`. Поведение для С и С++ в этом случае различается.

```
const LPSTR str = "str";
// аналогично
LPSTR const str = "str";
char * const str = "str";
```

- Инициализация указателя на `const` `char` посредством строкового литерала. Вот тут `const` применяется непосредственно к типу `char`. Ничего криминального.

```
const char* str2 = "str";
// аналогично
char const * str2 = "str";
char const * const str2 = "str";
const LPCSTR str2 = "str";
LPCSTR const str2 = "str";
```

- Инициализация указателя на `char` посредством `const` указателя на `char`. Ничего криминального.

```
char* w = str;
```

- Инициализация указателя на `char` посредством указателя на `const` `char`. Это ошибка как в С, так и в С++.

```
char* w2 = str2;
```

**Ответ для языка C:**

В стандарте C89 и C99 строковые литералы имеют тип "массив `char`" (без `const`), соответственно строковой литерал можно использовать для инициализации переменной типа `char *`. Однако попытка модификации буфера, на который будет указывать в этом случае указатель приводит к неопределенному поведению.

Если код в вопросе собрать как С код, то наличие только одной ошибки будет корректно - переменную с типом `char *` нельзя инициализировать значением с типом `const char *`.

**Ответ для языка С++:**

В современном С++ строковые литералы имеют тип "массив `const char`", соответственно строковой литерал для инициализации переменной типа `char *` использовать нельзя. Строка `const LPSTR str = "str";` должна вызывать ошибку, однако в Visual Studio старых версий по-умолчанию используется некомфорное поведение "как в С". Выключить его в VS2015 можно указав компилятору опцию [`/Zc:strictStrings-`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449508.aspx), в VS2017 опцию [`/permissive-`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance).

Comment: Если быть педантичным, в С++ строковые литералы всегда были "массив const char", то тем не менее в C++98 разрешалось использовать строковый литерал для инициализации переменной типа `char *`. Для этого делалось специальное исключение в правилах преобразования типов. Это исключение было убрано в С++11. Поэтому в старых VS (как и в старых GCC) поведение не столько "как в С", сколько "как в классическом С++". (Понятно, однако, что изначально это исключение было оставлено для совместимости с С.)